# Whats wrong with the curly braces why it didn't work?

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ATM {

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Account01 = 3000;
    int Account02 = 2000;
    int Account03 = 1000;
    String username;
    int pin, transaction, counter=1, menu, chooseAccount;
    int withdraw_amount, deposited_amount, transfer_amount, transfer_account = 0;


    do{
        System.out.print("Enter username: ");
        username = console.next();

        System.out.print("Enter PIN: ");
        pin = console.nextInt();


        if ((username.equalsIgnoreCase("Account01")) && (pin == 1234 )) 
        {
            System.out.println("PIN Accepted"); 
            System.out.println("\n\nSelect a menu:");
            System.out.println("[1] Balance Inquiry\n[2] Withdrawal\n[3] Deposit\n[4] Transfer Amount");
            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            menu = console.nextInt();
            do{
                if (menu == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\nBALANCE INQUIRY");
                    System.out.print("\nYour Current Balance is: " + Account01);
                }

                else if (menu ==2)
                {
                    do{
                        System.out.print("\n\nWITHDRAWAL");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        withdraw_amount = console.nextInt();
                        if(((withdraw_amount % 100) == 0) && ( (withdraw_amount >= 200) && 
                                (withdraw_amount <= Account01) && (withdraw_amount <= 10000) ))
                        {
                            Account01 = Account01 - withdraw_amount; 
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter<3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount!\n");
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter<=3);

                }

                else if (menu == 3)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        System.out.print("\n\nDEPOSIT");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        deposited_amount = console.nextInt();
                        if( ((deposited_amount % 100) == 0) && (deposited_amount <= 10000) )
                        {
                            Account01 = Account01 + deposited_amount; 
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter < 3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter <= 3);
                }

                else if (menu == 4)
                {

                    do{
                        System.out.print("\n\nTRANSFER PAYMENT");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        transfer_amount = console.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("[1] account01\n[2] account02\n[3] account03\n");
                        System.out.print("Chose account: ");
                        chooseAccount = console.nextInt();
                        if(chooseAccount == 1) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account01;
                        }
                        else if(chooseAccount == 2) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account02;
                        }
                        else if(chooseAccount == 3)
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account03;
                        }
                        else System.out.println("invalid number entered."); 

                        if( ((transfer_amount % 100) == 0) && (transfer_amount <= 10000) )
                        {
                            Account01 = Account01 - transfer_amount; 
                            transfer_account = transfer_account + transfer_amount;
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter < 3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter <= 3);
                }


                System.out.println("\n\n\nDo you want another transaction?\nType [1] if YES. Type [2] if NO");
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                transaction = console.nextInt();
                if (transaction == 1) 
                {
                    System.out.println("\n\nSelect a menu:");
                    System.out.println("[1] Balance Inquiry\n[2] Withdrawal\n[3] Deposit\n[4] Transfer Amount");
                    System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                    menu = console.nextInt();
                    do{
                        if (menu == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.print("\n\nBALANCE INQUIRY");
                            System.out.print("\nYour Current Balance is: " + Account01);
                        }

                        else if (menu ==2)
                        {
                            do{
                                System.out.print("\n\nWITHDRAWAL");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                withdraw_amount = console.nextInt();
                                if(((withdraw_amount % 100) == 0) && ( (withdraw_amount >= 200) && 
                                        (withdraw_amount <= Account01) && (withdraw_amount <= 10000) ))
                                {
                                    Account01 = Account01 - withdraw_amount; 
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter<3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount!\n");
                                else{
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter<=3);
                        }

                        else if (menu == 3)
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("\n\nDEPOSIT");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                deposited_amount = console.nextInt();
                                if( ((deposited_amount % 100) == 0) && (deposited_amount <= 10000) )
                                {
                                    Account01 = Account01 + deposited_amount; 
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter < 3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter <= 3);
                        }

                        else if (menu == 4)
                        {

                            do{
                                System.out.print("\n\nTRANSFER PAYMENT");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                transfer_amount = console.nextInt();
                                System.out.print("[1] account01\n[2] account02\n[3] account03\n");
                                System.out.print("Chose account: ");
                                chooseAccount = console.nextInt();
                                if(chooseAccount == 1) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account01;
                                }
                                else if(chooseAccount == 2) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account02;
                                }
                                else if(chooseAccount == 3)
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account03;
                                }
                                else System.out.println("invalid number entered."); 

                                if( ((transfer_amount % 100) == 0) && (transfer_amount <= 10000) )
                                {
                                    Account01 = Account01 - transfer_amount; 
                                    transfer_account = transfer_account + transfer_amount;
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter < 3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter <= 3);
                        }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThank You!!!\nGood Bye!!!");
                }
                break;

            }while((menu >= 1) && (menu <= 4));
            break;
        }


        else if ((username.equalsIgnoreCase("Account02")) && (pin == 4321)) 
        {
            System.out.println("PIN Accepted"); 
            System.out.println("\n\nSelect a menu:");
            System.out.println("[1] Balance Inquiry\n[2] Withdrawal\n[3] Deposit\n[4] Transfer Amount");
            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            menu = console.nextInt();
            do{
                if (menu == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\nBALANCE INQUIRY");
                    System.out.print("\nYour Current Balance is: " + Account02);
                }

                else if (menu ==2)
                {
                    do{
                        System.out.print("\n\nWITHDRAWAL");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        withdraw_amount = console.nextInt();
                        if(((withdraw_amount % 100) == 0) && ( (withdraw_amount >= 200) && 
                                (withdraw_amount <= Account02) && (withdraw_amount <= 10000) ))
                        {
                            Account02 = Account02 - withdraw_amount; 
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter<3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount!\n");
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter<=3);

                }

                else if (menu == 3)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        System.out.print("\n\nDEPOSIT");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        deposited_amount = console.nextInt();
                        if( ((deposited_amount % 100) == 0) && (deposited_amount <= 10000) )
                        {
                            Account02 = Account02 + deposited_amount; 
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter < 3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter <= 3);
                }

                else if (menu == 4)
                {

                    do{
                        System.out.print("\n\nTRANSFER PAYMENT");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        transfer_amount = console.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("[1] account01\n[2] account02\n[3] account03\n");
                        System.out.print("Chose account: ");
                        chooseAccount = console.nextInt();
                        if(chooseAccount == 1) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account01;
                        }
                        else if(chooseAccount == 2)
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account02;
                        }
                        else if(chooseAccount == 3) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account03;
                        }
                        else System.out.println("invalid number entered."); 

                        if( ((transfer_amount % 100) == 0) && (transfer_amount <= 10000) )
                        {
                            Account02 = Account02 - transfer_amount; 
                            transfer_account = transfer_account + transfer_amount;
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter < 3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter <= 3);
                }


                System.out.println("\n\n\nDo you want another transaction?\nType [1] if YES. Type [2] if NO");
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                transaction = console.nextInt();
                if (transaction == 1) 
                {
                    System.out.println("\n\nSelect a menu:");
                    System.out.println("[1] Balance Inquiry\n[2] Withdrawal\n[3] Deposit\n[4] Transfer Amount");
                    System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                    menu = console.nextInt();
                    do{
                        if (menu == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.print("\n\nBALANCE INQUIRY");
                            System.out.print("\nYour Current Balance is: " + Account02);
                        }

                        else if (menu ==2)
                        {
                            do{
                                System.out.print("\n\nWITHDRAWAL");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                withdraw_amount = console.nextInt();
                                if(((withdraw_amount % 100) == 0) && ( (withdraw_amount >= 200) && 
                                        (withdraw_amount <= Account02) && (withdraw_amount <= 10000) ))
                                {
                                    Account02 = Account02 - withdraw_amount; 
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter<3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount!\n");
                                else{
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter<=3);

                        }

                        else if (menu == 3)
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("\n\nDEPOSIT");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                deposited_amount = console.nextInt();
                                if( ((deposited_amount % 100) == 0) && (deposited_amount <= 10000) )
                                {
                                    Account02 = Account02 + deposited_amount; 
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter < 3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter <= 3);
                        }

                        else if (menu == 4)
                        {

                            do{
                                System.out.print("\n\nTRANSFER PAYMENT");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                transfer_amount = console.nextInt();
                                System.out.print("[1] account01\n[2] account02\n[3] account03\n");
                                System.out.print("Chose account: ");
                                chooseAccount = console.nextInt();
                                if(chooseAccount == 1) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account01;
                                }
                                else if(chooseAccount == 2)
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account02;
                                }
                                else if(chooseAccount == 3) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account03;
                                }
                                else System.out.println("invalid number entered."); 

                                if( ((transfer_amount % 100) == 0) && (transfer_amount <= 10000) )
                                {
                                    Account02 = Account02 - transfer_amount; 
                                    transfer_account = transfer_account + transfer_amount;
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter < 3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter <= 3);
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThank You!!!\nGood Bye!!!");
                }
                break;

            }while((menu >= 1) && (menu <= 4));
            break;
        }


        else if ((username.equalsIgnoreCase("Account03")) && (pin == 5555))
        {
            System.out.println("PIN Accepted"); 
            System.out.println("\n\nSelect a menu:");
            System.out.println("[1] Balance Inquiry\n[2] Withdrawal\n[3] Deposit\n[4] Transfer Amount");
            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            menu = console.nextInt();
            do{
                if (menu == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\nBALANCE INQUIRY");
                    System.out.print("\nYour Current Balance is: " + Account03);
                }

                else if (menu ==2)
                {
                    do{
                        System.out.print("\n\nWITHDRAWAL");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        withdraw_amount = console.nextInt();
                        if(((withdraw_amount % 100) == 0) && ( (withdraw_amount >= 200) && 
                                (withdraw_amount <= Account03) && (withdraw_amount <= 10000) ))
                        {
                            Account03 = Account03 - withdraw_amount; 
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter<3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount!\n");
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter<=3);

                }

                else if (menu == 3)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        System.out.print("\n\nDEPOSIT");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        deposited_amount = console.nextInt();
                        if( ((deposited_amount % 100) == 0) && (deposited_amount <= 10000) )
                        {
                            Account03 = Account03 + deposited_amount; 
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter < 3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter <= 3);
                }

                else if (menu == 4)
                {

                    do{
                        System.out.print("\n\nTRANSFER PAYMENT");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                        transfer_amount = console.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("[1] account01\n[2] account02\n[3] account03\n");
                        System.out.print("Chose account: ");
                        chooseAccount = console.nextInt();
                        if(chooseAccount == 1) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account01;
                        }
                        else if(chooseAccount == 2) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account02;
                        }
                        else if(chooseAccount == 3) 
                        {
                            transfer_account = Account03;
                        }
                        else System.out.println("invalid number entered."); 

                        if( ((transfer_amount % 100) == 0) && (transfer_amount <= 10000) )
                        {
                            Account03 = Account03 - transfer_amount; 
                            transfer_account = transfer_account + transfer_amount;
                            break;
                        }
                        // error catching
                        if(counter < 3)
                            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }while(counter <= 3);
                }


                System.out.println("\n\n\nDo you want another transaction?\nType [1] if YES. Type [2] if NO");
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                transaction = console.nextInt();
                if (transaction == 1) 
                {
                    System.out.println("\n\nSelect a menu:");
                    System.out.println("[1] Balance Inquiry\n[2] Withdrawal\n[3] Deposit\n[4] Transfer Amount");
                    System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                    menu = console.nextInt();
                    do{
                        if (menu == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.print("\n\nBALANCE INQUIRY");
                            System.out.print("\nYour Current Balance is: " + Account03);
                        }

                        else if (menu ==2)
                        {
                            do{
                                System.out.print("\n\nWITHDRAWAL");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                withdraw_amount = console.nextInt();
                                if(((withdraw_amount % 100) == 0) && ( (withdraw_amount >= 200) && 
                                        (withdraw_amount <= Account03) && (withdraw_amount <= 10000) ))
                                {
                                    Account03 = Account03 - withdraw_amount; 
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter<3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount!\n");
                                else{
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter<=3);

                        }

                        else if (menu == 3)
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                System.out.print("\n\nDEPOSIT");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                deposited_amount = console.nextInt();
                                if( ((deposited_amount % 100) == 0) && (deposited_amount <= 10000) )
                                {
                                    Account03 = Account03 + deposited_amount; 
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter < 3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter <= 3);
                        }

                        else if (menu == 4)
                        {

                            do{
                                System.out.print("\n\nTRANSFER PAYMENT");
                                System.out.print("\nEnter amount: ");
                                transfer_amount = console.nextInt();
                                System.out.print("[1] account01\n[2] account02\n[3] account03\n");
                                System.out.print("Chose account: ");
                                chooseAccount = console.nextInt();
                                if(chooseAccount == 1) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account01;
                                }
                                else if(chooseAccount == 2) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account02;
                                }
                                else if(chooseAccount == 3) 
                                {
                                    transfer_account = Account03;
                                }
                                else System.out.println("invalid number entered."); 

                                if( ((transfer_amount % 100) == 0) && (transfer_amount <= 10000) )
                                {
                                    Account03 = Account03 - transfer_amount; 
                                    transfer_account = transfer_account + transfer_amount;
                                    break;
                                }
                                // error catching
                                if(counter < 3)
                                    System.out.println("Error: Incorrect amount.\n");
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Card has been captured.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }while(counter <= 3);
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThank You!!!\nGood Bye!!!");
                }
                break;

            }while((menu >= 1) && (menu <= 4));
            break;
        }


        else if ((username.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) && (pin == 0000)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Program will be terminated!"); 
            break;
        }
        // error catching
        if(counter<3)
            System.out.println("Error: Incorrect username or password.\n");
        else{
            System.out.println("Card has been captured!");
            System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to continue?\nType [1] if YES. Type [2] if NO ");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            transaction = console.nextInt();
            if (transaction == 1) 
            {
                System.out.println("\n\nInsert your card."); 
                System.out.print("\nEnter username: ");
                username = console.next();

                System.out.print("Enter PIN: ");
                pin = console.nextInt();

            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("\nThank You!!!\nGood Bye!!!");
            }
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }while(counter<=3);
}
```

}

I'm making an atm machine program. What wrong with my program why it didn't work? Any suggestions guys? I really need to work this out though, I need it tom! :(

Comment: You have to describe how exactly your program fails to produce the expected results. It's hard to isolate your problem from all this code, especially if you don't state what it is.

Comment: Could you describe what you've tried so far, what you expect to happen and what it does so far?

Comment: Here's my problem when I run it: Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
 Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Comment: I try to run my program but this following error is always showing up  Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody. I'm trying to do an atm machine program guys.

Comment: hmmmm , you need to take care of your question's title , anyway wait until I read your code to answer

Comment: there is a "do" statement which lacks its ending }while(condition) I Think , what Ide you're using ? if netbeans or eclipse, didn't it show you where is the error located ?

Comment: well actually , it seems more than a brace lacks its closing one

Comment: I'm using eclipse bro, static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); the semicolon was underline with red and the end of the curly brace was also in red.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't compile, because you used a do{}while loop which has a general form:

```
do {
 statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

and you didn't add a expression part in three of them (from a beginning of code) .
You write statements without expressions.

I don't know your code, but it is enough to add:

```
                        }while(true);
                    }
                }while(true);
            }
        }while(true);
    }
}
```

to compile it.

However you should seriously think about dividing your code between multiple classes and methods, because it is very hard to read and maintain (as you probably know).